# Designing a 7 column Week Plan, horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to design a week plan showing three days of the week: today in middle, yesterday on left and tomorrow on right. But I want it to change on next and previous day so that clicking next day would take or scroll to (3 panels always showing) a new set of 3 days.

```
say today is Friday
3 columns showing by default
Left: Thursday
Middle: Today= Friday
Right: Saturday

when user click previous
Left: wednesday
Middle: Thursday
Right: friday
```

[Image](http://i62.tinypic.com/qp4i2p.png)

Using Bootstrap...

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
        <title>Justified Nav Template for Bootstrap</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="css/weekplan.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            WEEK PLAN
            <!-- ROW -->
            <div id="weekplan" class="row">
                <!-- Day 1 -->
                  <div class="col-md-4 eh hidden">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                              <h3>Day 1 - Sunday</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                              <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Day 2 -->
                  <div class="col-md-4 eh hidden">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                              <h3>Day 2 - Monday</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                              <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Day 3 -->
                  <div class="col-md-4 eh hidden">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                              <h3>Day 3 - Tuesday</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                              <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Day 4 -->
                  <div class="col-md-4 eh hidden">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                              <h3>Day 4 - Wednesday</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                              <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Day 5 -->
                  <div class="col-md-4 eh hidden-xs">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                              <h3>Day 5 - Thursday</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                              <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Day 6 -->
                  <div class="col-md-4 eh col-xs-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                              <h3>Day 6 - Friday</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                              <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Day 7 -->
                  <div class="col-md-4 eh hidden-xs">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                              <h3>Day 7 - Saturday</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                              <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <!-- /container -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.footer {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}
.col-md-4{
    border:1px solid #e0e0e0;

}
#weekplan {
    display: table;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#weekplan .eh {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
.panel-heading h3{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: @humble.rumble.6x3 i dont want the screen to scroll horizontally but more like a next or previous as in pagination but without changing to new HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pretty basic example of a three slide carousel, add more slides as required, it goes roundy-round thanks to insertBefore and insertAfter. if you want some animation try hiding it before you move it then show it once its been moved.

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9qec24b9/1/))

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="item">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            3
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            4
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void()" id="previous"><</a>
    <a href="javascript:void()" id="next">></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
}
.carousel {
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.item {
    font-size: initial;
    width: 33.3333%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.item:
#previous {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#next").on("click",function(){
    parent =  $(this).parent();
    parent.find(".item:first").insertAfter(parent.find(".item:last"));
});
$("#previous").on("click",function(){
    parent =  $(this).parent();
    parent.find(".item:last").insertBefore(parent.find(".item:first"));
});
```

Comment: I am using bootstrap3, and i am using col-md-4 for 3 columns but have to use hidden for 4 out of total 7 items. The above example helped a lot, need to look into bootstrap column behaviour + jquery to hide/show and before/after